# Angular: Display custom errors with AsyncValidatorFn if not Numeric input detected

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to write a custom number validator so in each user input should be checked if the value is numeric and then if not, should be shown an error message with mat-error
.
Here is the custom function, that returns an Observable if non Numeric

```
  private checkIfNum(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      const value = control.value;
      const numbersValidation = /\d/;
      if (!control.value) {
        return of({ numValid: 1 });
      }
      if (value.match(numbersValidation)) {
        console.log(of({ numValid: null }));
        return of({ numValid: null });
      } else {
        return of({ numValid: 1 });
      }
    };
  }
```

Here is the HTML, that should show error message, when non numeric input

```
<input #newPassword placeholder="*****" type="text" class="formField" formControlName="newPassword" matInput />
<mat-error *ngIf="changePassForm.controls.newPassword.hasError('minlength')">Password should be at least 8 symbols long</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="changePassForm.controls.newPassword.errors?.numValid">Password should include at least one number</mat-error>
```

Problem is second error message is never shown and the function checkIfNum() is triggered only if the first criteria('minLength') is met

here is the control in the form

```
newPassword: new FormControl("", userValidators.password, this.checkIfNum()),
```

Thanks for your time on this

Comment: Why do you add userValidators.password as part of the FormControl definition ?

Comment: userValidators.password comes from external file, where the validators for password are declared

Comment: export const userValidators = { password: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)],
};